# Why does jQuery's :contains count unexpected in my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a function that takes two parameters: The first is a string to count, the second the id of an HTML element in which the function is supposed to count occurrances of that string.

```
function countString(searchString, elementToSearchIn) {
    return $("#"+elementToSearchIn+" *:contains("+searchString+")").length;
    // In this example, call will be $("#searchElement *:contains('Apple')").length;
}

<table id="searchElement" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Apple</th>
    <th>Apple</th>
    <th>Banana</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Banana</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have setup a small fiddle demonstrating the problem: For example I have three times "Apple" in my `table`, but `countString` returns 6.

**Why is my function not returning the correct count?**

> https://jsfiddle.net/v10swbff/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `*:contains` is matching TD, TH *AND* TR. So it counts 6 (one for each TR and then the expected TH and TD counts). To fix it, you could check the TH and TD separately like so:

```
function countString(searchString, elementToSearchIn) {
    var thCount = $("#"+elementToSearchIn+" th:contains("+searchString+")").length;
    var tdCount = $("#"+elementToSearchIn+" td:contains("+searchString+")").length;
    return thCount + tdCount;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v10swbff/1/

Comment: I was just about to answer my own question as I found this out by checking what's contained in `$("#searchElement *:contains('Apple')")`. But what if you want to count only the elements that directly contain 'Apple', and not their parent element(s) - not knowing what type of elements that might be?

Comment: @connexo I would suggest asking another question with more detail and examples of the variations.

Answer (score 0):

As Cymen said, is matching tr elements in the search. I propose another function that you can use:

```
function countString(searchString, elementToSearchIn) {
    return $("#"+elementToSearchIn+" tr>*:contains("+searchString+")").length;
}
```

By just adding the 'tr>' you'll find only the th and td. :)

Comment: The `#elementToSearchIn` should be allowed any type of HTML element, that's the whole point of writing such a function.